# iTunes Store operation failed: Invalid signature

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, app-store

I want to submit a new application to the App Store. The application is build with IBM MobileFirst Platform 6.3 so the application itself is a Cordova application. When trying to validate before submitting it to the store, I get the following error message:

[image: iTunes Store operation failed.]

After searching for several hours. I can't find any solution which helps for me. The code signature seems to be OK, at least, I think so.

[image: Code Signing Identity]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I tried to run the application on an iPad 2 with iOS 7.2 and this works great. When connecting my iPhone 5s with iOS 8.3, I can't run the application as Xcode throws an error, he doesn't recognize my iOS version or something while Xcode is completely updated. The archive creation was successful, but the validation not.

New Signing:

[image: Code Signing Identity]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with the incorrect settings of the project, but with IBM Mobile First Platform. This platform creates an buildtime.sh file which is not signed. Apple won't allow this anymore, so this is why the error message keeps appearing.

For future reference: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/05/01/recent-changes-in-apples-app-submission-process/

Comment: Thanks, you helped me quite a lot! I think the URL you provided could solve a lot of other problems in the future.

Comment: I have updated the link. I don't know if it is relevant anymore as these changes are not 'recent' anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Your provisioning profile doesn't seem right.If there are so many "junk numbers" then we can say something's wrong.So I recommend you to check your steps or make everything from scratch:

Steps to make your app ready for App Store submit:

1-You create an App ID from member center

2-You create a Distribution Certificate

3-You create a Distribution Provisioning Profile with this App ID and Distribution Certificate included

4-Download this Provisioning Profile to your Mac

5-Double Click on this Provisioning Profile

6-in xCode make sure you selected the right team under Target -> General -> Team (This must be the team that includes App ID and Distribution Certificate that you just created)

7-Click xCode -> Preferences (or cmd,)

8-Under Accounts section, choose your team

9-Click "View Details" button

10-Click the "Refresh" button and wait for refreshing to finish

11-If you see the recently-created and downloaded provisioning profile, it is ok to click 'Done' button

12- Now, under Project and Targets, choose the recently-downloaded provisioning profile for "release" and "distribution" (also for the 'Any iOS SDK')

13- Then choose the right code signing identities that are derived from this provisioning profile (for release and distribution and also for 'Any iOS SDK')

14- Now it must be successsful

Comment: I tried to follow the tutorial, but with no success. The Provisioning Profile is now set to: iOSTeam Provisioning Profile: *bundle id* for both the Distribution and Release (the Distribution has a subitem which is 'Any iOS SDK') and the Code Signing Identity to iPhone Distribution: *company name*. But the same error keeps appearing. Any other idea?

Comment: 1: Already there. 2: Already did. 3: The Provisioning Profile is managed by Xcode, but I think this is alright. 4: Done. 5: This time nothing happens, but the certificate appears in my Keychain Access including the private key. 6: This was already selected, this time I get the 'No matching provisioning profiles found', the Fix Issue button does nothing, but reselecting the team appears to be fine. 7 - 10: Done. 11: Already there. 12: Done, Any iOS SDK is only present for Distribution. 13: I can only choose between: 'iPhone Developer', 'iPhone Developer: *name*' from profiles, 'Automatic' and

Comment: 'Other'. I tried to select the iPhone Developer under the "Identities from profile", but this doesn't work. (When this is selected, the other 'iPhone Developer' option disappears.

Comment: While comparing with another project I pushed past friday: The Code Signing Identity should be iPhone Distribution: *company name*. This is for another company, but the other distribution wasn't present. I chose other and pasted the iPhone Distribution for the right company, but this doesn't work.

Comment: 1- Is your bundle id is the same as your App ID which is used to create the Distirubition Provisioning Profile?
2-When you double-click the downloaded profile, there must be some zoom animation and it includes it to xCode by this way.
3- For debug, you assign "iOS Developer"
4- I also think it is ok but I recommend you to manage provisioning profiles by yourself.Create a Distiributon Provisioning Profile from member center.

@Sietse

Comment: Also are you setting provisioning profiles and code signing identities that are both under "Project" and under "Targets" ?

Comment: Yes, the Bundle ID is the correct one. The animation happens. I assigned iOS Developer now for debugging and currently I am trying with a profile I created myself, this way the iPhone Distribution is an option at the Distribution and Release signing identities. The Project and Targets (only one) has the same settings.

Comment: I have found the answer. The problem was IBM Mobile First created a Buildtime.sh, which is not allowed anymore as stated in an original post: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/05/01/recent-changes-in-apples-app-submission-process/